How can I prevent the user to add a public holiday who has the same date with other public holiday in django?
I am new to django. My model is this:
class PublicHoliday(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(_('Holiday Name'), max_length=100, unique=True)
  date_time = models.DateField(_('Holiday Date'))
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  def __str__(self) -> str:
      return self.name

@receiver(pre_save,  sender=PublicHoliday)
def save_current_year(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   new_intance_date_time = instance.date_time.replace(year=timezone.now(
       ).year, month=instance.date_time.month, day=instance.date_time.day)
   instance.date_time = new_intance_date_time

And the serializer is this:
class PublicHolidayCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PublicHoliday
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if PublicHoliday.objects.filter(date_time=validated_data['date_time']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This public day already exists")
        return super().create(validated_data)
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'date_time' in validated_data and PublicHoliday.objects.filter(date_time=validated_data['date_time']).exclude(pk=instance.pk).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This public day already exists")
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)

But when I create or update a public holiday who has the same dates as other public holidays doesn't work. How can I solve this

What do you mean by doesn't work? Do you get an error, or does the instance just get created? Please [edit] your question and share the relevant view.

No I don't get error but when I add a public holiday who has the same date with other public holiday the program add it


You should validate the data in validate method of the serializer
Try running the query  PublicHoliday.objects.filter(date_time=validated_data['date_time']) in a shell first
Most probably this is returning False, because validated_data['date_time'] might be a string
You should form a datetime object from validated_data['date_time'] before comparing it in query.


I have national holidays for specific country which are not in django admin when I add two public holidays with the same name or the same date are not saved but when I add a holiday with the same name or date with a national holiday saved


You should validate the data in validate method of the serializer
Try running the query PublicHoliday.objects.filter(date_time=validated_data['date_time']) in a shell first. Most probably this is returning False, because validated_data['date_time'] might be a string You should form a datetime object from validated_data['date_time'] before comparing it in query.

class PublicHolidayCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PublicHoliday
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return super().create(validated_data)
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'date_time' in validated_data and PublicHoliday.objects.filter(date_time=validated_data['date_time']).exclude(pk=instance.pk).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This public day already exists")
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        your_date_format = "%Y-%m-%d" #make sure this matches with the one you're sending through the API call
        # do the import at the top of your file
        import datetime from datetime
        incoming_date = datetime.strptime(attrs["date_time"],your_date_format)
        qs = PublicHoliday.objects.filter(date_time=incoming_date.date)
        if qs.exists():
             raise serializers.ValidationError("This public day already exists")
        return super().validate(attrs)


No it doesn't work now I can't add a date. When I add the date I have the error message "undefined"

So when you try to add an existing holiday, it fails?
Does it create an entry in PublicHoliday if it's a new date?

When I add a holiday with the same name or date with a public holiday (which not exists in django-admin) add it but when I add two holidays with the same date or name the second public holiday doesn't saved sorry about my english
